# Why server name not used in sftp get and put

Tags: command-line, sftp, scp

To transmit a file, `sftp` syntax is:

```
get /A/B/abc.txt /C/D/
```

In contrast, `scp` syntax for the same task is:

```
/A/B/abc.txt  username@servername:/C/D/E/
```

Why don't we need `username@servername` in case of `sftp`?

Comment: How did you start the `sftp` shell in the first place?

Comment: sftp username@servername, to connect to the server

Comment: So you have already mentioned it, haven't you?

Comment: In scp too, I use ssh user@server to connect initially. So how it differ?

Comment: I don't know why you do that. I just do `scp user@server ...` without having to run `ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

Because when that sftp get command is used, you are already connected to the server.  It would not be necessarily to tell it its own name again.

Comment: Agree.But in scp too, I connected using ssh username@servername. So what makes the difference?

Comment: It sounds like you logged into a shell on the other server using ssh and initiated the scp from there.  You do not need to first ssh into a server in order to run scp.  You can run scp from the local host and just ensure the local and remote arguments are the correct way around.